# ファイルからの文字列の読み込みについて

Tags: c

C言語で`xxxx yyyy`のような2組の文字列が複数並んだファイルを読み込み､線形リストに代入するとします｡
そこで以下のコードを書いたのですが､おそらく`first`と`last`がそれぞれの行に対して同じ領域を指してしまっているので､それを使って線形リストを作っても､すべての線形リストの要素が同じ`xxxx`と`yyyy`になってしまいます｡  そうすれば､ちゃんとした線形リストを作れるのでしょうか?

```html
char first[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];
char last[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];

while(fscanf(fp, "%s%s", first, last)!=EOF){
        //線形リストへの格納処理
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

おそらく`node->first_name = first`のようにしていると推測します。
これは、同じバッファ`char first[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];` を指すことになるので、
最後に処理した内容を指すことになります。
なので、別の領域を用意し内容をコピーするというような処理が必要になります。
具体的には次の様にします。
(非標準関数`strdup`が利用できるのであれば単に`node->first_name =strdup(first);`のようにできます。)

```
char *temp = malloc(strlen(first)+1);//別の領域を確保し
if(temp == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "mallocに失敗しました\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
strcpy(temp, first);//そこにコピーする
node->first_name = temp;
```

※malloc（strdupも同じ）で確保した領域は後で自分で開放する処理が必要です。